# how to create a function update using django and ajax

Tags: django, ajax, forms, sql-update

i have a django project that include a form where user insert data and save it into database using django function and ajax call.

without using the **ModelForm** in django.

now i want to allow the user to update the form  that he choose and once the user choose the form  the fields  must be displaying the existing data.

until now this was the create process.

i know that the update process will need the id of the object in order to be able to update the selected record.

the error :

> 'suspect' object is not iterable Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/update/23/ Django Version:   2.1.3
>   Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:   'suspect' object is not
>   iterable Exception Location:  C:\Users\LT
>   GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py
>   in render, line 165 Python Executable:    C:\Users\LT
>   GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe

## urls.py

```
 path('update/<int:pk>/',update,name = 'update'),
```

## update.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body %}


<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/linesAnimation.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/input-lineBorderBlue.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/dropDown.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/home.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/meta-Input.css' %}">
  <meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'%}"></script>
  <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="lines">
  <div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div><div class="line"></div>
  </div>

  {% for suspect in instance %}
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id='left-column-Input' class="formInput" include="select()"> 
      <div class="forminputs">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" autocomplete="off" required />
          <label for="fname" class="label-name">
            <span class="content-name" name="fname">{{suspect.suspect_name}}</span>
          </label>
      </div>

    <div class="forminputs">
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" autocomplete="off" required />
      <label for="lname" class="label-name">
        <span class="content-name" name="lname">{{suspect.suspect_last_name}}</span>
      </label></div>
    <div class="forminputs">
      <input type="text" id="fatherName" name="fatherName" autocomplete="off" required />
      <label for="fatherName" class="label-name">
        <span class="content-name" name="fatherName">{{suspect.suspect_father_name}}</span>
      </label></div>
    <div class="forminputs">
      <input type="text" id="motherName" name="motherName" autocomplete="off" required />
      <label for="motherName" class="label-name">
        <span class="content-name" name="motherName">{{suspect.suspect_mother_name}}</span>
      </label></div>
    <div class="formSelect">
      <select id="gender" name="gender" required>
        <option value="">{{suspect.gender}}</option>
        <option value="1">male</option>
        <option value="2">female</option>
      </select></div>
    <div>
      <textarea id="content" name="textarea" class="textArea" placeholder="content">{{suspect.content}} </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="home-Button">
      <button id="edit" name="edit" type="submit">Edit</button>
      <button id="clear" name="clear" type="submit">Clear</button>
    </div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){                           
      $("#edit").on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        fName=$('#fname').val()
        lName = $('#lname').val()
        fatherName = $('#fatherName').val()
        motherName = $('#motherName').val()
        gender = $('#gender').val()
        content=$('#content').val()

        $.ajax({
              url:'/blog/update',
              method:'POST',

          data: {
                FName: fName,
                LName: lName,
                FatherName: fatherName,
                MotherName: motherName,
                Gender: gender,
                content:content,

                // data:data
              },

              headers:{
                'X-CSRFToken':'{{csrf_token}}'
            }
          }).done(function(msg){
              location.href='/blog/list'
          }).fail(function(err){
            alert(err)
        })
      })
    })
  </script>
</form>

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

## views.py

```
   def update(request,pk):
   #deny anonymouse user to enter the  detail page
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect("login")
    else:
      suspect = get_object_or_404(suspect, pk=pk)
      if request.method =="POST":
        suspect = suspect()
        suspect.suspect_name = request.POST['FName']
        suspect.suspect_last_name = request.POST['LName']
        suspect.suspect_father_name = request.POST['FatherName']
        suspect.suspect_mother_name = request.POST['MotherName']
        suspect.gender = request.POST['Gender']
        suspect.content = request.POST['content']
        print(suspect.suspect_name)

        suspect.save()

      context = {
        "title":member.member_name,
        "instance":member,
      }

    return render(request,'blog/update.html',context)
```

i will appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a simple example that you can extend for your case.

In the template where the user have a link to update his profile :

```
<a href="{% url 'Profile-Update' %}"> Update Profile </a>
```

in your urls.py

```
path('update_profile/', views.ProfileUpdate, name='Profile-Update')
```

in views.py

```
def ProfileUpdate(request):
  current_user = request.user
  if request.method == 'POST':
    get_username = request.POST.get('username', '').strip()
    suspect.objects.filter(pk=current_user.pk).update(username=get_username)
    return HttpResponse('Profile Updated')
  else:
    return render(request, 'prorile_update_form.html', {'current_user': current_user})
```

in prorile_update_form.html :

```
<form class="update_profile">
{{ csrf_token }}
  <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ current_user.username }}">   
  <button class="submit_update">Save changes</button>
</form>
<!-- So the current user username will be displayed on the input as a value -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.submit_update').on('click', function(){
              $.ajax({
             url: '/update_profile/',
             method : 'POST',
             data: $('.update_profile').serialize(),
             beforeSend: function() {
              // things to do before submit
             },
             success: function(response) {

              alert(response)
              }
              });
  return false;

});
</script>
```

If the user have a different model that he can update so you may want to pass the id of the form as a variable in the url like this :

```
path('update_profile/<int:pk>', views.ProfileUpdate, name='Profile-Update')
```

And you interpret the variable on your view like this :

```
def ProfileUpdate(request, pk):
```

you can use the pk to fetch the required model and than make all the required updates based on the form that you will provide.

Comment: i will edit my question and add the update that is done on the function and the template  can you take a look and tell me what is the error ?

because  the system display an error.

Comment: If my answer was correct for your first question can you accept it please ?

Comment: how can i check if it works for me ? i did update the question and add the function in order if you can check it and tell me if its write or wrong and where is the error

Comment: anw i will accept your answer and thank you for your time and help but hope that you will answer to the updated question

Comment: i past the error note that to enter the update page is through a button called update  detail  then user can update the data existing on the form based on the selected id

Comment: Not just this line// local variable 'suspect' referenced before assignment// please post the few lines before this one

Comment: it seams you do not have the answer to my problem

Comment: I am looking at it, wait a sec please

Comment: can't be done by using filter () and update()? like this:

` 
        dbEntry = suspect.objects.filter(pk = pk ).update(suspect_name = fName, suspect_last_name = lName, suspect_father_name = fatherName,
                            suspect_mother_name = motherName, gender = gender, content=content)
        dbEntry.save()`

Comment: in this line // suspect = get_object_or_404(suspect, pk=pk)standard // why you have added "standard" ??

Comment: its a comment  but maybe on pasting the code here i forgot to put #

Comment: suspect = get_object_or_404(suspect, pk=pk), i think i ve found it, change the variable name here to something else than suspect

Comment: i change suspect ==> obj   now  this error 'suspect' object is not iterable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196785/discussion-between-farhani-walid-and-django-dg).